# How to generate unique id based on start date and end date for the next 40 years in SQL table

Tags: sql, database-administration

I would like to generate unique id for the next 40 years for the following list of names. Pay attention to the start and end date. not every name has the same start and end date.

```
ID  Name    year    Start Date  End date 
1   Dance   2050    1/1/2050    12/31/2050
2   Dream   2050    7/1/2049    6/30/2050
3   Mocca   2050    7/1/2049    6/30/2050
4   Noway   2050    7/1/2049    6/30/2050
5   Papa    2050    7/1/2049    6/30/2050
6   Vintage 2050    1/1/2050    12/31/2050
7   Wave    2050    7/1/2049    6/30/2050
```

Comment: Use a guid, or a hash function if there are no duplicate entries

Comment: ID Name year Start Date End date
1 Dance  2050 1/1/2050 12/31/2050
2 Dream 2050 7/1/2049 6/30/2050
3 Mocca  2050 7/1/2049 6/30/2050
4 Noway 2050 7/1/2049 6/30/2050
5 Papa 2050 7/1/2049 6/30/2050
6 Vintage 2050 1/1/2050 12/31/2050
7 Wave 2050 7/1/2049 6/30/2050

Comment: Can you elaborate ?

Comment: The column 'id' appears to be unique...why not use it?

Comment: I can make the Id Identity to avoid duplicate . The question is how to add the 7 names for every year and also add the appropriate start date and end date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to have a lookup table, where each row contains one of the items you wish to track. Add a column that generates a default unique surrogate key (an “identity” column, in SQL Server, and virtually all RDBMSes have something similar) whenever a row is added.

That works if the value is just a date range, such as Jan 1, 2017 through Dec 31, 2017. If your unique value is based on the date range and the user name (example: MJ8 + Jan 1, 2017 + Dec 31, 2017), well, that’s probably a central table in your database schema, and is even more deserving of a surrogate key.

Surrogate keys also help manage situations where you have duplicates (say, two entries for Smith + Jan 1, 2017 + Dec 31, 2017) -- one could be ID = 3, the other ID = 8710.

A good argument for not basing a unique value on your “source data” is that it is `smart data`. Your unique id might end up being a string (or a very big number) like 2017010120171231. Awkward, but it works. The danger is, users (or developers) might see this and decide that, rather than “track it back to the source” (by perhaps joining on this key to the table containing the source data), they’ll just parse the string and convert each half back into the original date. This is generally not a good idea, as it slows down processing, produces hard to read (and debug and maintain) code, and can make things very difficult if the data being referenced changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a unique ID for a given date range, then I suggest you do just that - create a table for date ranges, assign each one a unique id (such as primary key?) and then use a foreign key in your existing table to reference the date range table instead of explicitly putting the start and end dates on there.

If you really need those dates, use a view that joins the two tables.